# Crazy trouble with addEventListener

Tags: javascript, leap-motion

I have a div with **id="inn"**
and then a code like this:

```
var zin = document.querySelector("div#inn");
zin.addEventListener("click", function(e){
    if (count <= maxzoom) {
        startZoomIn();
    }
})
```

The crazy trouble is that, if I click with mouse, all works fine, but if I use (as needed) the over cursor (I'm workin' with **Leap Motion**), it don't work, it seems isn't recognized...
The very strange thing is that an absolutely equal code, for different element, works perfectly; and that, exactly the same code works fine on a different page...

I'm workin' around this trouble by many hours, and maybe are stultyfied..., but in any way I try to approach to solve, the trouble stay always there...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just had a quick loop at the Leap Motion JS Reference and it looks like you need to [handle gestures](https://developer.leapmotion.com/documentation/javascript/api/Leap.Gesture.html) (such as click differently)

Additionally, you might find [LeapCursor.js](https://github.com/roboleary/LeapCursor.js?v=02) helpful.
It should make it easier for you to do something like:

```
$("#inn").click(function() { alert('Leap cursor click!'); });
```

Comment: Thank you! Anyway, finally I solve it. The cause is that I use a same class for _zoom buttons_ and the element to zoom, and this result incompatible for the js library that manage the zoom...